# Backbone.history has already been started

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am getting an error "Backbone.history has already been started" on my Backbone.js app. Here's my code.

```
(function ($) {
    // model for each article
    var Article = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    // collection for articles
    var ArticleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Article
    });

    // view for index page
    var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#wrapper'),
        render: function (){
            var template = Handlebars.compile($("#main_hb").html());
            $(this.el).find('#main_content').html(template);
            return this;            
        }   
    });

    // view for listing blog articles
    var ArticleListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#wrapper'),
        render: function(){
            var js = this.model.toJSON();
            var template = Handlebars.compile($("#articles_hb").html());
            $(this.el).find('#main_content').html(template({articles: js}));
            return this;    
        }
    });

    // main app
    var ArticleApp = Backbone.Router.extend({
        // setup routes
        routes: {
            ""  : "index",
            "blog"  : "blog"
        },          
        index: function(){
            var main = new MainView({});
            main.render();
            return this;
        },          
        blog: function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'blogs/articles', 
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {},
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var articles = new ArticleCollection(data);
                    var view = new ArticleListView({model: articles});
                    view.render();
                }       
            });
            return this;
        }

    });

    // let's start the app!
    articleApp = new ArticleApp();
    Backbone.history.start();

})(jQuery);
```

The app itself seems like it's working fine. But that error in Chrome is mysterious.

Comment: The app looks like a definition, not a start.  This code is run when it's loaded, not when `$(document).ready()` is called.  Could you be loading it twice, or calling it again with a `$(document).ready()` call?

Comment: My suggestion would be to debug it with the non-minified version of backbone.

Answer (score 8):

12/30/2013 UPDATE: looks like this might be a common issue, i decide to bold the reason.

I ran into same issue and solved it. The reason is I

**`imported the js file twice`**

So I may suggest you check the page which contains this script see if it was introduced twice.

Answer (score 3):

Yujings said it right! It imported the js twice. *updated*
My "fix" (is definitely more of a workaround) was to place this in the router.

```
Backbone.history.stop();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Probably not the most ideal, but it got the job done in a naive fashion.

Comment: As alluded to by Nick Pridorozhko's answer, you could also test the value of `Backbone.History.started` (note the capitalization of 'History'). That said, you (generally) shouldn't need to stop and start the Backbone.History, so this smells more of 'workaround' than 'fix'.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem because of Turbolinks in my Rails 4 app.
This workaround helped me. Maybe it will help you too:

```
initialize: ->
  new MyApp.Routers.Posts
  Backbone.history.start() unless Backbone.History.started
  $(document).on "page:change", ->
    Backbone.history.stop()
    Backbone.history.start()
```

Found this answer here: https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails/issues/134

Comment: Your answer might be more helpful if it were written in the same language as the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be ok. Are you sure you load it exactly once? If you put console.log() just before history.start(), is the log printed exactly once?

In general you get this error, when history.start() is called multiple times. You need to locate the second call, I'm afraid. The code you posted here is not enough to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and it was because I was doing **require_tree .** in my **application.js** file and I had precompiled my assets.

Check that you don't have a **public/assets** file if you're going to be using **require_tree .** in your **application.js** file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using requirejs, check that your script doesn't include itself - just add console.error() call at start and see how many times it comes up. I had it come up because I copied optimization configuration to linear execution.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
   articleApp = new ArticleApp();
   Backbone.history = Backbone.history || new Backbone.History({});
   Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this, a router should have initialize `Backbone.history` for you.

Comment: Yikes, you're going to throw away the old `Backbone.history` without shutting it down? The old instance will still exist, which will continue polling the browser 20 times/second (and trying to react to URL changes). If you really need to re-start it for some reason, call `Backbone.history.stop()` first -- and then just restart it, don't re-instantiate it.